# How to access the user's selection in the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to write an extension for chrome that operates on a user's selection on a webpage. How can I get access to the selected text from a chrome plugin?

Thanks,
Joshua

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Chrome plug-ins, but I imagine they have access to the regular `window` object. This is how you do it in a web page:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var selectedText = sel.toString();
```

Comment: Didn't know about that. This is so much better than my solution. Thanks for sharing @Tim +1

Answer (score 0):

Check this (experimental) [copy](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.clipboard.html#method-executeCopy) stuff. I think it's just what you need.

Also, the context menu api (not experimental) gives you a [onClickData](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/contextMenus.html#type-OnClickData) which contains the selection text.

Comment: chrome.experimental.clipboard.executecopy doesn't describe what happens with the copied data, other than the implication that it might copy selected text to the clipboard. No paramaters are passed to the callback function. I don't see how that helps me.